# C# Loop through SPListItemCollection with Where clause

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have an SPQuery, that I want to loop through twice.  First is the initial loop through, getting all the values for every row

```
foreach (SPListItem timelineItem in timelineCol)
                        {
```

within this foreach I would like to do a second foreach of timelineCol BUT with a WHERE statement, something along the lines of

```
foreach (SPListItem timelineItemException in timelineCol.Where(n => n["workflowExcpetions"]  = an int I have already retrieved from the item)
```

Essentially I am getting an int value from the initial timelineItem, and if it exists, I have to run through all the rows again, looking for any other rows containing this value, but I don't want to loop through all of them, just the ones matching my criteria.

Comment: First store the result of the where statement in a variable. (collection). Then loop that collection. Use ToList() to be sure it is stored as an object.

Comment: I need the results of the Where statement in order to store them.  The above is what I want, but does not actually work.